# How to have the app open a different activity for the first time it is launched and a different one from then on?

Tags: java, android, xml

Suppose there are two activities A1 and A2.
A1 is like a sign in page.
A2 is the main homepage.
How do I get A1 to appear the first time the user starts the app but once he has signed in, A2 should be the screen the user sees first after restarting the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should have a fixed launching activity..
so what you can do that when activity launched show a image for 1 or 2 sec after that you can jump to any activity ..for the first time app open ,you can choose a activity and after that when you again open the app it will show another activity..here is the code

```
 public class class_name extends AppCompatActivity {
 public static final String MyPREFERENCES2 = "MyPrefs" ;
 SharedPreferences sharedpreferences2;
 public boolean isFirstRun;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_class_name);


    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            checkFirstRun();

        }
    }, 3000);




}
   public void checkFirstRun() {
    System.out.println("its in check first run");
    isFirstRun = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE2",  MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("isFirstRun", true);
    if (isFirstRun){
       startActivity(new Intent(class_name.this, new_activity1.class));

        getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE2", MODE_PRIVATE)
                .edit()
                .putBoolean("isFirstRun", false)
                .commit();

    }
    else{
         startActivity(new Intent(class_name.this, new_activity2.class));

        }
     }
}
```

Comment: This is the code for the Java file of the picture activity you mentioned, right?

Answer (score 1):

Use preferenceManager to set a flag...

```
final String FIRST_TIME_KEY = "com.example.app.MainActivity.firstTimeKey";
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
boolean isFirstTime = sp.getBoolean(FIRST_TIME_KEY, false);
if(isFirstTime) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sp.edit();
    edit.putBoolean(FIRST_TIME_KEY, true);
    edit.apply();

    //Start the frist time only activity
} else {
    //Start the normal regular activity
}
```